# Expect script: Read Base64 password from file

Tags: linux, base64, tcl, expect

I have created a script that will connect to a server using SFTP. 
To avoid putting the password in the script as plain text, I'm planning on putting it in a file encoded in base64. 
I can read from the file no problem. But I don't know how to decode base64 with Expect. 
So, for now, the script reads the file and puts the password (directly) into the script. How to decode it? 
I'm ready to move all the script back to Shell/bash if there's a good way to do such thing.

Thank you. Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set myPassword [open "sftp_auth.cfg" r]
set data [read $myPassword]

spawn sftp myUser@111.111.111.111
expect "*assword:"
send "$data\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /repository\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "get Example.sh /home/User/Example2.sh\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
interact
```

Comment: for those looking how to read username and password from file in an expect script: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/expect-read-passphrase-from-a-file-287216/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Tcl's [`exec`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm) command to decode the password. For example:

```
[STEP 101] # cat foo.exp
set base64_passwd UGFzc3cwcmQ=
set passwd [exec echo $base64_passwd | base64 -d]
puts $passwd
[STEP 102] # expect foo.exp
Passw0rd
[STEP 103] #
```

Comment: Since the encoded password is already in a file, let base64 read that file: `set passwd [exec base64 -d sftp_auth.cfg]`

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

1. since you're using ***S***ftp, the best method is to use public key authentication. Search for "sftp public keys"
2. you could install [the `tcllib` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/tcllib), then do

   ```
   package require base64
   set f [open sftp_auth.cfg]
   gets $f data
   close $f
   set pw [::base64::decode $data]
   ```
3. call out to `base64`

   ```
   set pw [exec base64 -d sftp_auth.cfg]
   ```

Better make sure that auth file has no world readable permissions: base64 is not exactly cryptographically secure.

Comment: Yes I know about base64. I was planning on suggesting the idea of using public/private key authentication to the team anyways. 
Thank you

Comment: sometimes storing a password in clear text on the filesystem is the simplest solution, if you can live with the obvious lack of security. In this, there is really no point in obfuscating the password, particularly since the expect script is also in plain text and the "decrypting" method is there to see.

Comment: Yes, I am totally aware of that thank you for pointing it out. I will dig deeper in this subject and see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Tcl 8.6, base64 support (including decoding) is built in.

```
set f [open "sftp_auth.cfg" r]
set password [binary decode base64 [read $f]]
close $f
```